# Change if conditon dynamic ? (python)

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, if-statement

Hey guys i want to change the if condition in a function dynamic.

```
def func(<):
     if y<x:
        return x

def func(=):
         if y=x:
            return x
```

i want just the condition changed, any ideas?

Comment: First, your indentation is wrong for the `=` func. Second, what are `y and x`. Right now they are local variables. Third comparison is `==` not `=`. The latter is assignment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use the operators like `=` and `<` directly. But you can import them from `operator`:

```
from operator import le, eq

def func(op):
    if op(x, y):
        return x

func(le)       # → x < y
func(eq)       # → x == y
```

BTW the comparison operator is `==` not `=`.